# Iteratively and adaptively increasing the network size during training

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reference-request, training, neuroevolution

For an experiment that I'm working on, I want to train a deep network in a special way. I want to initialize and train a small network first, then, in a specific way, I want to increase network depth leading to a bigger network which is subsequently to be trained. This process will be repeated until one reaches the desired depth.

It would be great if anybody heard of anything similar and could point out to me some related work. I think in some paper I read something about a related technique where people used something similar, but I don't find it anymore.

Comment: it is common when dealing with images to train this way using progressive resizing

Comment: @juvian thanks. that keyword was helpful

Answer (score 5):

**Neuroevolution Through Augmenting Topologies** or **NEAT** may be what you are referring to. The original paper by Kenneth O. Stanley is [here](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf)

NEAT combines a neural network and a genetic algorithm. Instead of using back propagation or gradient descent to "train" your network, NEAT creates a population of very simple neural networks (no connections) and evolves them with **fitness evaluation, crossover,** and **mutation.** The genome syntax: every connection gene has a few settings. In node, Out node, Weight of connection, activated, and innovation. **In, Out,** and **Weight** values are the same as regular neural networks. **Enabled** and **Disabled** genes are well, enabled and disabled. The innovation value is possibly the most defining feature of NEAT, since it allows for crossover of different topologies and historical tracking of each connection.[image]NEAT can mutate or change both its weights and connections, so for example, `Parent1` and `Parent2` has 5 of the same connections, represented by innovation / ID numbers 1 through 5. Since they have the same connection nodes, the genetic algorithm will randomly pick either `Parent1 weight` or `Parent2 weight`. The excess and disjoint genes are inherited from the more fit parent.[image: NEAT crossover] NEAT will then mutate each genome, shown in the image below.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read any relevant paper about this, but I have seen some implementations based on what you are describing, arbitrarily called **DGNN (Dynamic Growing Neural Network)**.

Hope this term can help your search.

Answer (score 0):

At [DeepChess](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09667) they trained stacked autoencoders:

> **Training Pos2Vec**: We first trained a deep belief network (DBN), which would later
> serve as the initial weights for supervised training. The DBN is based
> on stacked autoencoders which are trained using layer-wise
> unsupervised training. The network consists of five fully connected
> layers of sizes: 773–600–400–200–100. We initially trained the first
> layer (i.e., a 3-layer (773–600–773) autoencoder), before fixing its
> weights and training the weights of a new (600–400–600) autoencoder,
> and so on.

I suppose this matches your criteria, although the network's architecture isn't very flexible. They don't introduce skip-connections etc.